# mouse move for list view in MFC to get index of list control

Tags: mfc

I have created application in which I am getting mouse move event on list view.
Que- How to get the index of list view, when mouse is moved on items of list view.?

I wanted to know the index from list view of the mouse curser.

Answer (score 1):

CListCtrl::HitTest() takes a CPoint and tells you if the mouse was over an item and, if so which item and which part of the item.